# Package Humanizer.Core.XX 2.14.1 is not compatible with net8.0 (.NETCoreApp Version=v8.0)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, nuget, .net-8.0, humanizer

After upgrading my ASP.NET Project using EF Core from .NET 7 to .NET 8, i get these warnings that prevent me from installing any NuGet packages in Rider. The project still builds and compiles. I tried removing all `bin` and `obj` directories in my solution followed by a NuGet force restore already, but no change so far.

My .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
        <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
        <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
        <LangVersion>12</LangVersion>
        <Authors>Felix Winterleitner</Authors>
        <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
        <Title>MyApp</Title>
        <RepositoryType>git</RepositoryType>
        <SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="8.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="5.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer" Version="5.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy" Version="8.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.1">
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.1">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="8.0.0">
            <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions" Version="8.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="8.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="7.3.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I got rid of the issue by explicitly adding the Humanizer.Core NuGet package to my project (before, it was implicitly installed with the EFCore package).